# BeautifulSoup: parse only part of the page

Tags: html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I want to parse a part of html page, say

```
my_string = """
<p>Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
   <a href="#">Link1</a>
   <a href="#">Link2</a>
</p>
<img src="image.png" />
<p>One more paragraph</p>
"""
```

I pass this string to BeautifulSoup:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(my_string)
# add rel="nofollow" to <a> tags
# return comment to the template
```

But during parsing BeautifulSoup adds `<html>`,`<head>` and `<body>` tags (if using lxml or html5lib parsers), and I don't need those in my code. The only way I've found up to now to avoid this is to use `html.parser`.

I wonder if there is a way to get rid of redundant tags using lxml - the quickest parser.

**UPDATE**

Originally my question was asked incorrectly. Now I removed `<div>` wrapper from my example, since common user does not use this tag. For this reason we cannot use `.extract()` method to get rid of `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags.

Comment: Have you tried using MinimalSoup instead of BeautifulSoup?  (Same library, different constructor).  It's supposed to be less strict about that sort of thing.

Comment: I tried but I couldn't understand how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem using [.contents](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) property:

```py
try:
    children = soup.body.contents
    string = ''
    for child in children:
        string += str(item)
    return string
except AttributeError:
    return str(soup)
```

I think that `''.join(soup.body.contents)` would be more neat list to string converting, but this does not work and I get

> TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, Tag found

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
soup.body.renderContents()
```

Answer (score 0):

lxml will always add those tags, but you can use [`Tag.extract()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) to remove your `<div>` tag from inside them:

```
comment = soup.body.div.extract()
```